# Angular 2 Dynamic Component loading ngOnChanges lifecycle hook call

Tags: angular

Is it expected behavior that ngOnChanges lifecycle hook is not called in case of dynamic component loading?
Only the constructor, ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit are called for me. However according to the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) it should be called before ngOnInit.

I am loading the component like this:

```js
@ViewChild('place', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

   private componentRef: ComponentRef<MyLoggerComponent>;

   constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     const componentFactory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyLoggerComponent);
     this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
     this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
   }
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6GA6F6wrnUVs1P6KQVHx)

Comment: ngOnChanges() is only called when Angular bindings update inputs and dynamic created components don't support @Input() or @Output()

Comment: Regular component will fire ngOnchange if it has @Input porperty and it's updated This plunker won't work http://plnkr.co/edit/w2Cc1ssw30ZcP0M2gFdJ?p=preview

Comment: Here's working plunker with regular component http://plnkr.co/edit/sFl84z0XY6OpCa5imTvz?p=preview

Comment: See also this thread https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8903

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to discussion https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8903 dynamic components loading should not trigger `ngOnChanges` in child component even after calling `detectChanges` because this event is reserved only for template bindings.

If your child component is loaded only in the dynamic way you can use Javascript setter instead of `ngOnChanges`. Here is the example:

```js
export class DynamicallyLoadedComponent {
  private _property: string;
  get property(): string { return this._property; }
  set property(newVal: string) {
    if (this._property === newVal) { return; }
    this._property = newVal;

    this.onChanges();  // instead of ngOnChanges
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonder why they are limiting the use of `ngOnChanges` binding for template bindings.

Comment: @sirwojtek do you have a sample code that works, please

Comment: @SirWojtek what version of angular are you using in this example?

Comment: @Rich It is working on version 5.2.4 (and probably older)

Comment: @aguetat the solution comes from my company code, will try to extract Plunker